# Запятые перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

Нужны ли запятые перед "как":
"Нельзя требовать результатов(,) как от Песталоцци, а платить(,) как Митрофанушке"?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужны - здесь идет сравнение.